# What's a good backpack for traveling to big cities?

Tags: cities, chicago, backpacks

I'm going to Chicago soon and I'm looking for a backpack that will fit all of my needs.  I'm going to be there for an extended weekend so I want to be able to bring several days worth of clothes with me on the way to there. Once I'm there, I'm planning on removing all the clothes in my hotel so I can carry the backpack around the city. I want to be able to carry basic stuff like a water bottle, extra phone batteries, a small tablet, etc but still have room for any kind of souvenirs I buy. I also don't really want to look like too much of a tourist there.

I'm having a hard time finding one that's big enough to bring clothes to the city but still small enough to walk around all day with. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Finding one backpack for that is tough since travel and city duty are very different.  Have you considered packing the city pack in a larger case for travel?

Comment: I'm looking at the Osprey Farpoint 55 Travel Backpack which looks like it has one big backpack for clothes and a smaller detachable one for the day, I'm just afraid it's a little too big overall and a little too expensive.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. The Q&A format of our site is unfortunately very ill-suited to product recommendations, because there is no one right answer. You might be able to get some help in the chat.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm going to Chicago soon and I'm looking for a backpack that will fit
>   all of my needs. I'm going to be there for an extended weekend so I
>   want to be able to bring several days worth of clothes with me on the
>   way to there.

I guess the easiest way is for you to go to a shop like REI or similar, ask them about your needs and your budget and they will help you find the perfect quality/price ratio compared to the size of bag that you want.

After all, the job of a salesperson is not solely to sell you something but to advise you on the best possible outcome for the customer. Therefore you should make a quick search about what the market has to offer and what you would like.

Also, one of the most important thing you should look for buying a packpack for traveling is the comfort and the security. Cause you don't want your stuff stolen ...